# prevent empty input from returning undefind and instead return an empty string

Tags: javascript, php, get

As the title suggests, i have a registration form, and since i know that javascript can be disabled, i decided to check for empty inputs in my server sided php, but all empty inputs return `undefined` as the string, instead of just an empty string, is there anyway (*in PHP*) i can prevent it from returning or make sure that the value is known to be empty ? (the user could still pick a name or username that is **undefined**)
The Javascript Function:

```
var lnk = 'register.php?n=' + $('#fname').value + '&f=' + $('#pnumb').value + '&m=' + $('#elecm').value + '&l=' + $('#uname').value + '&p=' + $('#pword').value + '&p2=' + $('#pconf').value;
        $.post(lnk, function (data) { //Do something with data }
```

the PHP:

```
<?php
//databse info
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "phptest";
//Getting values from link
$comname = $_GET['n'];
$phone = $_GET['f'];
$mail = $_GET['m'];
$uname = $_GET['l'];
$pass = $_GET['p'];
$conf = $_GET['p2'];
//Checking if any value is left empty
if (empty($comname)) {
    echo '1';
}
elseif (empty($phone)) {
    echo '2';
}
elseif (empty($mail)) {
    echo '3';
}
elseif (empty($uname)) {
    echo '4';
}
elseif (empty($pass)) {
    echo '5';
}
elseif (empty($conf)) {
    echo '6';
}
```

Comment: I think your javascript has some errors. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @FunkDoc why wouldn't value work with that ?

Comment: I think the correct syntax is $('#fname').val()

Comment: @FunkDoc still giving the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, shouldn't it be

```
$('#fname').val()
```

when using jQuery? And while we're at it, using jQuery for just selecting an element by ID is throwing away performance for a little bit of lazyness. Why not use

```
document.getElementById('fname').value
```

?

It might only be milliseconds, but they add up in larger scripts, so why not use vanilla JS when you can acheive what you need? :)

And to answer your question:

```
(document.getElementById('fname').value || '')
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you, i know i added it a bit late but still way early from anyone's comment or response, but i wanted the check to happen IN the php, which is another file in my server, because JS can be disabled after all.

Comment: There is no way that an empty input submitted by an ordinary POST/GET request without any JavaScript interfering would make the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable contain the string "undefined". So I don't really get why you would want to catch something server-side as a No-JS-Fallback that will only be present when JS is activated? ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this example to see if a var is undefined , if it is it turns in a empty string, if not, returns the variable itself

```
var string = ( typeof(string ) == 'undefined' ) ? "" :string ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prefer this

> $("#someID").value || "default value"

It will allow you define the default value if the userInput is falsy (i.e empty string, undefined etc)

If the user enters undefined, it will not be `undefined` but string "undefined"

```js
var lnk = 'register.php?n=' + ($('#fname').value||"") + '&f=' + ($('#pnumb').value||"") + '&m=' + ($('#elecm').value||"") + '&l=' + ($('#uname').value||) + '&p=' + ($('#pword').value||"") + '&p2=' + ($('#pconf').value||);
        $.post(lnk, function (data) { //Do something with data }
```